# Cannot get constructor method to print to the console in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I am having an issue in terms of trying to get the constructor method to print to the console when the object has been instantiated from within the `main` method:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message message = new Message();
        System.out.println(message.helloWorld());
    }  
}
```

Here is the object that has been instantiated:

```
public class Message {

    public void Message() {
        // constructor method
        System.out.println("Constructor Method!");
    }

    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

I assumed the constructor method would print to the console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not declare a constructor:

```
public void Message() {
```

Constructors have no return type; this is a method.  Remove `void`:

```
public Message() {
```

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

```
 public void Message() {
```

It is not a constructor, it is a method thus it is not called upon creating the instance of your class

it should be this:

```
 public Message()
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you thinking that constructor method should print?
It will not print. Because  you have not declare a constructor. You just only have 2 methods.

This is not a constructor. this is just another method. Constructors doesn't have a return type.

```
public void Message() {
        // constructor method
    System.out.println("Constructor Method!");
}
```

But if you have like this

```
public Message() {
        // constructor method
    System.out.println("Constructor Method!");
}
```

Then it is a constructor and it will get print

Answer (score 2):

Wrong constructor declaration , `public void Message() { }` should be `public Message() { }`:

```
public class Message {

public Message() { // <-- Here's the correct constructor declaration
    System.out.println("Constructor Method!");
}

public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello, World!";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is not a Constructor but a normal method, you have to remove the void to be a constructor:

public Message() {...}

NOT

public *void* Message(){...}